# how to call function with timeout on legacy .net 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

I have some legacy code that was write in .net 3.5

I need to add some ability to call some method ( io method ) with timeout => that mean that after X second i need to throw exception if its not done.

Using Task is not possible because on .net 3.5 there is no Task.
How to do it ?

Comment: What kind of code do you have? Please, share with us

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski    C# .net 3.5

Comment: this is simple code that need to call function with timeout .. no need to shared this kind of code ... just how do it without task

Comment: You can use `IAsyncResult` and `Begin...` methods from APM

Comment: beginInvoke and EndInvoke is async call - its not belong to my question

Comment: *beginInvoke and EndInvoke is async call - its not belong to my question* That's why the code is needed

Comment: @Yanshof you can register wait for `IAsyncResult` and throw an exception when timeout happens. Of use `Wait` and throw an exception, if operation isn't completed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a delegate with the same signature with your method and then call it using `BeginInvoke` and block the current thread using `WaitOne()` method with timeout. If operation isn't completed after timeout, you'll throw an exception

```cs
public delegate void AsyncMethodCaller(...);

AsyncMethodCaller caller = new AsyncMethodCaller();

IAsyncResult result = caller.BeginInvoke(...);

result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeout);

if(!result.IsCompleted)
{
    //throw an exception
}
```

You can see mode detailed example in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iasyncresult?view=netframework-4.8). And keep in mind, that this code blocks the current thread. If you need an asynchronous wait, there is a different approach, using `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` method from `ThreadPool` [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.registerwaitforsingleobject?view=netframework-4.8)

```cs
ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle,
        (state, timeout) =>
        {
            if (timeout)
            {
                 //do something
            }
        },
        state, timeout, true);
```

`state` variable in this case is handler of your operation (IO or any other). You can pass it and abort an operation when timeout happens

Comment: with one small caveat ... it will prolly not cancel ongoing IO operation

Comment: For the handling old fashioned `HttpWebRequest` we are using the second approach with `RegisterWaitForSingleObject`. I guess, if IO operation handler supports aborting, the same thing can be used. Also OP didn't mentioned any IO operations, just a simple method

Comment: from question *some method ( **io method** )*